# Node js code minify to prevent theft from hosted server admin

Tags: node.js, express, minify, uglifyjs

I want to minify whole node js project into one file OR minified version of each file in my project. I know minifying node.js code wouldn't give me extra performance in server side rather I wanna do this to prevent theft of my code from server admin in which I am gonna host my web app. However regarding this I found following thread but its not helpful yet.

[How to minify a node.js application? (Server side node.js, not client side javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22511393/how-to-minify-a-node-js-application-server-side-node-js-not-client-side-javas)

I haved used to **browserify** to minify client side code but when gonna minify node.js project it gives error of dependencies as I tried according to above thread.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [node.js - Code Protection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951302/node-js-code-protection)